# FIRStorageReference observing changes Swift

Tags: swift, firebase

Is there a way to listen for changes to FIRStorage children like there is for FIRDatabase ".childChanged?" I have profile images in my storage and whenever users change them, I want to trigger my app to reCache them with my SAMCache method.

Comment: There isn't a way to listen to changes to FIRStorage. Instead, you could generate the downloadUrl and then store that in the database. Then you can listen to changes to that child in the database.

Comment: Thank you. Does it have to be the actual URL? Could I just store a random String that gets changed every time the user changes the picture then listen for that?

Comment: You're right, it could just be a random String. I just figured you may need the downloadUrl anyway.

Comment: Thank you. If you want to post the answer I will approve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a way to listen to changes to FIRStorage. Instead, you could generate the downloadUrl or a random value and then store that in the database. Then you can listen to changes to that child in the database.

Example modified from the documentation:

```
// Upload the file to the path "images/rivers.jpg"
let uploadTask = riversRef.putData(data, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
  guard let metadata = metadata else {
    // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
    return
  }
  // Metadata contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
  let downloadURL = metadata.downloadURL
  ref.child("/users/\(userId)/profileImage").setValue(downloadURL)
}
```

And then also attach a listener to ref.child("/users/(userId)/profileImage").